# Adding a callback URL to an existing connected app

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I have a connected app I created a long time ago. I would like to add an additional callback url to the app. Before I do that, I need to be 200% sure that existing users that are already connected to the app will remain connected after I make this change.

Can adding a callback url somehow revoke existing connections to my app? (for example, by changing the consumer id or secret)

If not - is this documented somewhere?